# how to get a higher priority to ZFS module relative to rsync?

Tags: linux, centos7, rsync, zfs

I have a zfs on linux storage, that use from rsync for replication,

when rsync is running on a dataset for replicate it on a another pool,

when i want create a dataset on primary pool , it get a long time for

create a dataset,

do way exist i get a higher priority to zfs module relative to rsync module?

Thanks for your helps,
The Best Regards,

Comment: See command `ionice`. Another thing you can usually do without consequences (providing there are no things like network timeouts setup) is use `kill -STOP` to temporarily pause the rsync process, then make it continue with `kill -CONT`.

Comment: thanks, i want when linux up, it occur as automatically in module level , is it possible?

Comment: Even better, don't use `rsync` to sync ZFS filesystems.  `rsync` doesn't scale well because it has to ***discover*** differences between the two filesystems.  ZFS already ***knows*** the differences if you use ZFS snapshots to synchronize two ZFS filesystems.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, but it is hard for manage snapshots for backup, for a while, snapshot get many space from storage, because i have must maintain last snapshot,

Comment: @AliHamid You can create a “bookmark” from the snapshot instead and then delete the snapshot, which doesn’t require any extra storage on the source system, but still allows you to do a zfs send from the bookmark to some new snapshot you create in the future.